# jQuery reload div's content (dynamically rendered)

Tags: jquery, plugins, refresh, reload

I have a div that is generated html via Expression Engine.  I'm using ajax submit:

```
$('#login-form').ajaxForm({  
    // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
    // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
    success: function() { 
    $("#panel").RELOAD!!();//Just refresh this div!
    } 
});
```

I just want the #panel div to reload/refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you looking for something like that:

```
$('#login-form').ajaxForm({  
    success: function( data) { 
    $("#panel").html( data);//Will insert new content inside div element.
    } 
});
```

FIX:

```
$('#login-form').ajaxForm({ 
    target: '#panel', //Will update the "#panel"
    success: function( data) { 
    alert( "Success");
    } 
});
```

Comment: Expression Engine does an auto-return after submission.  I can't tell if this is working...I think it is, but EE tries to reload the whole page for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any of the methods listed in jQuery's "manipulation" section are going to do what you want: http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation

Answer (score 0):

And for your pretty fade in

```
success : function(data) {
   $("#panel").hide().html(data).fadeIn('fast');
}
```

Comment: This is a syntax question:  Why do you have single quotes around 'fast' instead of double?