# Update dynamically generated class with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an email based app in php (in Codeigniter f/w).
I want to be able to change the unread message to read when clicked (I have 2 classes: read0 and read1).
I can see the content of the message instantly but would like to change it to "read" (to 1) as well.

```
foreach ($all->result_array() as $row){
print "<tr><td class=read".$row['read']."><a href='#' class='list' name=".$row['au_id'].">".$row['read']."</a></td></tr>";
    }
```

and ajax looks like:

```
$('.list').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('contact/clickMsg'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data:'app_id='+this.name,
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#msg_content').html(msg);
            
        }
    });
$.ajax({ 
        
        success: function( smth) { 
            $('a').html(smth);//Will insert new content inside div element.
        } 
    
    });
```

[image: I have to unread msgs]
[image: Smth is wrong]

I have looked at [jQuery reload div's content (dynamically rendered)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932777/jquery-reload-divs-content-dynamically-rendered) and I think I am missing something.
I have also tried $('a').replace(smth) but getting the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i misunderstood your question. Seeing your code, the selector $('a') can be really ambiguos. I think you need use $('.list') looking for the specific class. But in other words, If you need refresh a specific  tag, you need do it by the name. A good idea is that in smht var comes the ID of the row and the value, so you parse it with a string function, and you use a part of that parse (the id) into the selector and the second (the value) into the html. Something like:

$('name=' + my_returneded_ajax_id).html(my_returneded_value)

So in this way you can refresh exactly the row that you really updated in the db.

Comment: no I want to display the value that has been modified in database instantly... I have a field (read in  my table) which has value of 1 or 0... if I click on 0 I want to be able to change it to 1. It updates in db but I can see it on the page after I refresh it.